# Why isn't $scope updated when bound properties of services are updated by other services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one service for handling data, and one for logic.

```
app.service('DataService', function() {
  this.stuff = [false];
  this.setStuff = function(s){
    this.stuff = angular.copy(s);
  }
});
```

The data service has a `set` function and a `data` property.

```
app.service('LogicService', function(DataService, $http) {
  DataService.setStuff(["apple", "banana"]);
  $http.get("./data.json").then(function(res){
    DataService.setStuff(res.data.stuff);
  });
  
});
```

I am assigning a property of the data service to the controller for binding to the DOM.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService, LogicService  ) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, World!";
  $scope.stuff = DataService.stuff;

  //This is the only way I could get it to work, but isn't this JANKY?
  //$scope.$watch(
  //  function(){
  //    return DataService.stuff
  //  },
  // function(n,o){
  //   $scope.stuff = n;
  // })
 
})
```

If I 'seed' the data service when the logic service is instantiated, and then later update it following an `$http` call, the DOM reflects the 'seeded' or initial value, but does not update.

Is there something fundamental I am missing in my understanding of the digest loop?

If I add a $watch function in my controller, all is well, but this seems yucky.

**//FIXED//**

@scott-schwalbe 's method of using `Object.asign()` works nicely, preserves my original structure, and is one line.

```
this.setStuff = function(s){
   Object.assign(this.stuff, s);
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KNdASxvFkmLfIpmAY7Ce?p=preview)

(sorry for titlegore)

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained. Once you update that demo this question is broken for future readers and we shouldn't have to go off site to review what your issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data property is an object and is binded to the scope, then the scope will update whenever the object changes as long as you don't dereference it (eg data = x). Are you reassigning data object on the $http call?

An alternative to your current code to keep the reference using Object.assign

```
app.service('DataService', function() {
  this.stuff = [false];
  this.setStuff = function(s){
    Object.assign(this.stuff, s);
  }
});
```

Comment: yes...elaborate on breaking the reference because that's exactly what's happening

Comment: Thank you, please elaborate.  I've edited the original post with code samples, if you'd like to provide an alternative.  Any link to docs or an article would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, World!";

   //Get stuff data from your service, this way you stuff lives in your service  
   //And can be accessed everywhere in your app.   
   //It also makes your controller thin. Which is the top priority
   $scope.stuff = DataService.getStuff();
   //Or async
   DataService.getStuffAsync()
      .then(function(val){
       $scope.asycStuff = val;
   });

    this.clickFromAButton = function(){
      DataService.setStuff(["apple", "banana"]);
    };
});


app.service('DataService', function() {
  this.stuff = [false];
  this.asyncStuff;

  this.setStuff = function(s){
    this.stuff = angular.copy(s);
  };

  this.getStuff = function(){
      return this.stuff;
  };

  this.getStuffAsync = function(){
     //If i already fetched the data from $http, get it from the service.  
     return this.asyncStuff || $http.get("./data.json").then(function(res){
        //When i fetch it for the first time I set the data in my service
        this.asyncStuff  = res.data;
        //and I return the data
        return res.data;
     });
  };

});
```

This is a good 'pattern' to follow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting "stuff" on scope. Put your `DataService` object on scope.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService, LogicService  ) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, World!";
  $scope.DataService = DataService;
  //$scope.stuff = DataService.stuff;
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{DataService.stuff}}
  </body>
```

The `$interpolate` service will automatically places a `$watch` on `DataService.stuff`. Thus there is no need to do it inside your controller.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/02UtvZzlSx1EOfHBAXMh?p=preview).